# How can i select all the data from the two tables "incoming_calls" and the "outgoing_calls" tables in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I Want to select all the calls from the incoming_calls table and the outgoing_calls table together. Basically i am creating api and i want to get the data from these two tables and to paginate them.
How can i do that? Anyone!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: $json['incoming_calls']=incoming_calls::get();
        $json['outgoing_calls']=outgoing_calls::get();
        return response()->json($json);

Answer (score 0):

Do the two tables have a field in common? Or do you want the two results separate?

To select data and paginate simply use

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
```

See [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) or you can also use [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

So, about your case, you'll need to create pagination manually ([more info](https://informagenie.com/2559/creer-manuellement-pagination-laravel/) [FR]), so collection should have the same structure.

This code can do the thing.

```
$calls = IncomingCall::all()->merge(OutgoingCall::all());

//creating of pagination

$page = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('page', 1);
$perPage = 10;
$calls = new \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator(
    $calls->slice(($page - 1) * $perPage),
    $perPage,
    $page,
    [
        'path' => \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()
    ]
);
```

Comment: but why it don't have the last page no. and the last page url?